# Jquery assignment fails when inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, unassigned-variable

I have a jquery which works correctly when I do this:

```
var slide = [];
slide[1] = 
    {
        hide: function() {
            $("#slide-1").hide();
        },
        show: function() {
            $("#slide-1").show(2000);
        }
    };
slide[1].show(); <<< works fine
```

But if I try it in a loop in fails:

```
for (var i=1; i <= totalSlides; i++) {
  slide[i] = 
    {
        hide: function() {
            $("#slide-" + i).hide();
        },
        show: function() {
            $("#slide-" + i).show(2000);
        }
    };
};
slide[1].show();  << unassigned
```

any idea?

Comment: Ӫ_._Ӫ's answer at the bottom nailed it I think, but here's a live example of more or less the same thing that's happening if that can be of help. http://jsfiddle.net/X4VQV/

Comment: @richardneililagan: Very nice example to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Make sense. Because I wrapped 'i' in closures, it's stored as a pointer instead of a value. When slide[1].show() is called later, i points to nothing, and throws error "undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're saying that it is *"unassigned"* but I'm guessing that the function is just not doing what you want.

This is a common issue. All the functions you're creating in the loop are referencing the same `i` variable. This means that when the function runs, it is getting the value of `i` where it was left *after the loop finished*.

You need to scope the variable that your functions reference in a new variable environment to retain the value from the loop. To do that, you need to invoke a function, and have that function reference the current `i` value.

Like this:

```
function generate_functions( j ) {
     //    v----- DO NOT place the opening brace on the next line, after the
    return {              // return statement, or your code will break!!!
        hide: function() {
            $("#slide-" + j).hide();
        },
        show: function() {
            $("#slide-" + j).show(2000);
        }
    };
}

var slide = [];

for (var i=1; i <= totalSlides; i++) {

    slide[i] = generate_functions( i );

};

slide[1].show(); // should work
```

I created a function called `generate_functions()`, and invoked it in each iteration, passing `i` as an argument.

You'll notice that `generate_functions()` received the value as the `j` parameter. You could call it `i` as well, but changing the name makes it a little clearer IMO.

So now your functions are referencing the local `j`. Because a new variable environment is created with each invocation of `generate_functions()`, the functions inside that you create will be referencing the `j` value *of that specific variable environment*.

So the `generate_functions()` *returns* the object that contains the functions that were created in each new variable environment, and that object is assigned to `slide[i]`.

Comment: To expand on that a tiny bit, what you're creating is a __Javascript closure__. It can be a powerful language [feature] but it can be a big pain in the buttocks if you're not familiar with it (and thus, create it accidentally, like in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Is the $("slide-1" + i).show(2000) a typo, or the error?

Answer (score 0):

Add `var slide = [];` above the `for` loop.